# Reading text to variables in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file with this format:

```
1:0:d=2016080100:REFC:entire atmosphere:anl
2:415003:d=2016080100:RETOP:cloud top:anl
```

I need to read 2016080100 and 2016080100 on each line and put it into a variable.
How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: Do you mean in a shell script?

Comment: What do you want to do with the variable then?

Comment: Yes, I need to read the number after "d=" in a shell script and then put that value into a variable.

Comment: Which shell? A POSIX shell (e.g. ash, dash, bourne) or an advanced shell, e.g. bash, zsh, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it. You can use `awk` to split the line on colon and select the row you want (by the first column), then use `awk` again to split the third field on equal sign to get the date. To store the result as a variable in a shell script, use command substitution with backticks ``` `` ``` or `$()`).

```
# Select the row where the first column is equal to "1".
FOO=$(awk -F: '$1 == "1" { print $3 }' </path/to/your/file | awk -F= '{ print $2 }')
# Select the row where the first column is equal to "2".
BAR=$(awk -F: '$1 == "2" { print $3 }' </path/to/your/file | awk -F= '{ print $2 }')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is based on mwp's answer, just a tweaked a bit to automate exporting into variables, but this is assuming your first column is unique and third column always starts with d=

```
`cat file.txt | awk -F: '{print "export var"$1$3}'`
```

it would export them into var1d and var2d based on your example:

```
echo $var1d
2016080100
echo $var2d
2016080100
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file `data.txt` is:

```
1:0:d=2016080100:REFC:entire atmosphere:anl
2:415003:d=2016080100:RETOP:cloud top:anl
```

and you want to create a variable (an array) that contains all the values after the equal sign. Then you can do:

```
d=($(sed -n 's/.*=\([^:]*\).*/\1/p' data.txt))
```

Verify that the captured data is what you want:

```
echo ${d[@]}
2016080100 2016080100
```

Explanation of command:

```
d=($(sed -n 's/.*=\([^:]*\).*/\1/p' data.txt))
            's/                   ' data.txt     substitution command with data.txt as input
               .*=\([^:]*\).*/\1/                keep only number after equal sign  
     sed -n                     /p               print replaced text
d=($(                                       ))   get output of sed and store in array d
```

Comment: The only problems is the question is tagged `shell` -- and there are no arrays in POSIX shell. Double check with the questioner whether he has arrays available -- and just which shell he is using. (I suspect he does, but you need to confirm)

Comment: True, I answered this question without looking at the tags and overlooked this important detail.